# Read file and only get integers and keep going till end

Tags: c, file

```
#include <stdio.h>


int getIntegers(char *filename,int a[]);

int main(void) {
    /////
    FILE *fp;
    char file[10] = "random.txt";
    fp = fopen(file, "w");
    fprintf(fp, "1 2 -34 56 -98 42516547example-34t+56ge-pad12345\n");
    fclose(fp);
    /////

    int i;

    int a[100]; 
    int n = getIntegers(file,a);
    //Here i want to print out what i got from getIntegers. What it should put out = "1 2 -34 56 -98 42516547 -34 56 12345"
    if (n > 0) 
    {
        puts("found numbers:");
        for(i = 0;i < n; i++)
            {
                printf("%d ",a[i]);    
            }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}

int getIntegers(char *filename, int a[])
{
    int c, i;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
//I want what this code does to be done with the commented code under it. This will give "1 2 -34 56 -98 42516547"
    while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&i)==1) 
    {
        printf("%d ",i);
    }
    fclose(fp);

// I want this code to give  "1 2 -34 56 -98 42516547 -34 56 12345"  
//    while ((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) 
//    {           
//        for(i = 0; i < c;i++)
//        {
//            fscanf(fp, "%1d", &a[i]);
//        }
//    }
//    return i;
}
```

I have a file with numbers and words/letters in it. With this code I get the integers untill first letter, but i want to continue until EOF. And then return those numbers and print them out in main. I tried but could not get it to work. What should/could i do to get this working? Or what am I doing wrong.

Comment: `int getIntegers()` does not return any value.  Code does not save anything in `a[]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple issues:

`int getIntegers()` does not return any value.  Code does not save anything in `a[]`. Array limits not enforced.

Commented code does not check the return value of `fscanf()`.

**Code needs to consume 1 character when `fscanf()` returns 0 and then try again.**

When `fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i])` returns 0, it means the input is not numeric *and `fscanf()` did not consume any of the non-numeric input*.  So read 1 character and try again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 100

int getIntegers(char *filename, int a[], int n);

int main(void) {
  FILE *fp;
  char file[] = "random.txt";
  fp = fopen(file, "w");
  if (fp == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file for writing\n");
    return -1;
  }
  fprintf(fp, "1 2 -34 56 -98 42516547example-34t+56ge-pad12345\n");
  fclose(fp);

  int a[N];
  int i;
  int n = getIntegers(file, a, N);

  puts("found numbers:");
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("%d ", a[i]);
  }
  putchar('\n');

  return 0;
}

int getIntegers(char *filename, int a[], int n) {
  int i;
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  if (fp) {
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      int cnt;
      do {
        cnt = fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
        if (cnt == EOF) { fclose(fp); return i; }
        if (cnt == 0) fgetc(fp);  // Toss 1 character and try again
      } while (cnt != 1);
      // printf("%d ", i);
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
  return i;
}
```

Output

```
found numbers:1 2 -34 56 -98 42516547 -34 56 12345
```

Comment: Thanks for explaing the issues I had. With that in mind it helped me understand much better.